# Please help. I get this SQL Error: Msg 206, Level 16

Tags: sql, sql-server

I get this error message:

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 9
>  Operand type clash: datetime2
> is incompatible with int

with this part of my query:

```
select * from Attendance where workdate = (Select Max(Workdate)-1 from Attendance)
order by WorkDate desc
```

Note: I am new to sql and still learning.

Comment: Here's a good explanation https://database.guide/sql-server-error-206-operand-type-clash/

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: @jarlh That error message looks to be SQL Server, but I could be wrong.

Comment: And isn't datetime2 a SQL Server data type?

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18

Answer (score 1):

Use DATEADD to add or subtract from dates.

```
select 
    * 
from 
    Attendance 
where 
   workdate = 
   (Select DATEADD(day,-1,Max(Workdate)) from Attendance)
order by WorkDate desc
```

Also, if you have the ability to store the maximum working day in a variable beforehand, prefer that over the sub-select on every row.

Comment: Check your edits.   Your original answer was using a DATEDIFF, not a DATEADD - which is why I offered my solution.

Edit history, eh?

Comment: I suspected this...I never saw your answer for some bizarre reason.  Had I seen it, I would have deleted my answer.  Apologies for questioning you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to subtract one day from the max work date in your table, then use the `DATEADD()` function:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Attendance
WHERE workdate = (SELECT DATEADD(day, -1, MAX(Workdate)) FROM Attendance)
ORDER BY WorkDate DESC;
```

Comment: If we're assuming SQL Server (which there are plenty of hints for), you'd want to `DATEADD` that -1, not `DATEDIFF`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yeah...you're right